# Silverlight/WPF - RadioButton.IsChecked bound to a smart boolean source

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, radio-button

I sometimes get tired of creating individual IsChecked*SomePropertyName* for each radio button on a MVVM UI.  The alternative would be to name each button and find the one where IsChecked=true and then translate its name to something meaningfule in my **strong text** model.

It would be nice if there was a way backed into Silverlight and/or WPF to have a collection that encapsulates all this estranuous logic.  An example use case in my code would be:

```
<Page x:Name="idHost"
      ...>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RadioButtonSource.CurrentEnabledButton, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='Selected Filter: {0}', TargetNullValue='Selected Filter: not selected', ElementName=idHostPage}" />
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=RadioButtonSource[Inherited], Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=idHostPage}"
             IsThreeState="False"
             GroupName="PostFilter"
             Content="Inherited" />
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=RadioButtonSource[Direct], Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=idHostPage}"
             IsThreeState="False"
             GroupName="PostFilter"
             Content="Direct" />
...
```

code behind for the page would look like:

```
public partial class MyPage : Page {

    public MyPage() {
        this.RadioButtonSource = new RadioButtonSource();
    }

    public RadioButtonSource RadioButtonSource {
        get { return (RadioButtonSource)GetValue(RadioButtonSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RadioButtonSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadioButtonSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RadioButtonSource", typeof(RadioButtonSource), typeof(MyPage), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to my question that I already developed. A single class that encapsulates all this busy work into one reusable class.

```
public class RadioButtonSource : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    #region Member Field(s)

    Dictionary<string, bool> m_RadioButtonFlags;

    #endregion

    #region Event(s)

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion

    #region Con/Destructor(s)

    public RadioButtonSource() {
        this.m_RadioButtonFlags = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Exposed Proper(y|ies)

    public string CurrentEnabledButton {
        get {

            var q = from key in this.m_RadioButtonFlags.Keys
                    where this.m_RadioButtonFlags[key]
                    select key;

            return q.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    [IndexerName("Item")]
    public bool this[string radioButtonName] {
        get {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(radioButtonName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("radioButtonName");
            if (this.m_RadioButtonFlags.ContainsKey(radioButtonName))
                return this.m_RadioButtonFlags[radioButtonName];

            var returnValue = false;
            this.m_RadioButtonFlags.Add(radioButtonName, returnValue);
            return returnValue;
        }
        set {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(radioButtonName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("radioButtonName");

            if (this.CurrentEnabledButton == radioButtonName)
                return;

            this._ChangeFlags(radioButtonName);

            if (this.PropertyChanged != null) {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentEnabledButton"));
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Method(s)

    void _ChangeFlags(string radioButtonName) {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(radioButtonName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("radioButtonName");
        if (!this.m_RadioButtonFlags.ContainsKey(radioButtonName))
            this.m_RadioButtonFlags.Add(radioButtonName, true);

        foreach (var key in this.m_RadioButtonFlags.Keys.ToArray()) {
            if (key != radioButtonName)
                this.m_RadioButtonFlags[key] = false;
            else
                this.m_RadioButtonFlags[key] = true;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```